# Unable to redirect page on form submission in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web

I'm trying to make an API call and redirect a page upon form submission using React. Here's some qualities of the issue I'm running into:

- All that happens upon form submission is the page reloads
- If I set the submission function to run on click, it will redirect the page as expected
- Everything else in the function runs as expected upon submission

I've removed the API code as it's irrelevant for this question:

```
const Booking = () => {
```

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
window.parent.location = '/intuit-app/thankyou';}
```

```
  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <FormWrap>
          <Icon to="/intuit-app">Intuit</Icon>
          <FormContent>
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <FormH1>Enter your email, then pick a date and time for your consultation</FormH1>
              <FormLabel htmlFor='for'>Email</FormLabel>
              <FormInput type='email' onChange={handleInputChange} required />
              <FormButton type="submit" value="Submit"
              >Submit</FormButton>
            </Form>
          </FormContent>
        </FormWrap>
      </Container>
    </>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to prevent the default behavior of the browser.

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.parent.location = '/intuit-app/thankyou';
}
```

Comment: That worked, thanks so much!